# Can XNA & Visual Studio be run in VMware Fusion on Mac OS X?

Tags: virtualization

Is it possible to run XNA & Visual Studio from a machine under VMware Fusion running on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done the setup before. You won't get hardware acceleration but the setup does work and if your not doing any work that requires hardware acceleration it should be fine.

I previously did demos for Tech-Ed on gaming development using this setup without any problems.

For hardware acceleration you will need to use Boot Camp.